# How to add text stroke in Photoshop by script?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I would like to use Photoshop Script (or Photopea Script) to add the stroke on text layer but i don't know how to do.
Please see the details as below.

- Text layer name : MSG_1
- Stroke color : #ff0000
- Stroke pixel : 3

Note : I need to use only the script to add stroke in my project.

[image: I want a script to add stroke like this image]

I have been searching many forum for week but nothing work for me.
So, I register on stackoverflow to ask my first question. Please help T^T

Answer (score 0):

The (action manager) code you need gets generated by the [scriptlistener plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html) and written to to a log file. You can sift through that to get what you want.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 

var stroke = 3; // stroke width in pixels
var rgb = [255,0,0];  // stroke RGB colour

var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
var desc44 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref3 = new ActionReference();
var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
var idLefx = charIDToTypeID( "Lefx" );
ref3.putProperty( idPrpr, idLefx );
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref3.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc44.putReference( idnull, ref3 );
var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
var desc45 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idScl = charIDToTypeID( "Scl " );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc45.putUnitDouble( idScl, idPrc, 100.000000 );
var idFrFX = charIDToTypeID( "FrFX" );
var desc46 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idenab = charIDToTypeID( "enab" );
desc46.putBoolean( idenab, true );
var idpresent = stringIDToTypeID( "present" );
desc46.putBoolean( idpresent, true );
var idshowInDialog = stringIDToTypeID( "showInDialog" );
desc46.putBoolean( idshowInDialog, true );
var idStyl = charIDToTypeID( "Styl" );
var idFStl = charIDToTypeID( "FStl" );
var idOutF = charIDToTypeID( "OutF" );
desc46.putEnumerated( idStyl, idFStl, idOutF );
var idPntT = charIDToTypeID( "PntT" );
var idFrFl = charIDToTypeID( "FrFl" );
var idSClr = charIDToTypeID( "SClr" );
desc46.putEnumerated( idPntT, idFrFl, idSClr );
var idMd = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );
var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
var idNrml = charIDToTypeID( "Nrml" );
desc46.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, idNrml );
var idOpct = charIDToTypeID( "Opct" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc46.putUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 100.000000 );
var idSz = charIDToTypeID( "Sz  " );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc46.putUnitDouble( idSz, idPxl, stroke );
var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
var desc47 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
desc47.putDouble( idRd, rgb[0] );
var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
desc47.putDouble( idGrn, rgb[1] );
var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
desc47.putDouble( idBl, rgb[2] );
var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
desc46.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc47 );
var idoverprint = stringIDToTypeID( "overprint" );
desc46.putBoolean( idoverprint, false );
var idFrFX = charIDToTypeID( "FrFX" );
desc45.putObject( idFrFX, idFrFX, desc46 );
var idLefx = charIDToTypeID( "Lefx" );
desc44.putObject( idT, idLefx, desc45 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc44, DialogModes.NO );



// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL
```